# Every bounded linear operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Is there an elementary proof of the result that every bounded linear operator from $\ell^p$ to $\ell^q$ is compact , where $ 1 \leq q  < p < \infty$.

The only proofs I found were using deep properties of reflexive spaces and compact operators.

Is there a proof where one only uses the characterization of compact subsets of $\ell^p$ spaces in some way?

Comment: This is known as Pitt's theorem. See a proof [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-04/S0002-9939-08-09617-2/S0002-9939-08-09617-2.pdf).

Comment: Ya, I have heard of Pitt's theorem. That is the proof I had mentioned in the 2nd paragraph of my question. I was looking for a more elementary proof

Comment: And the paper linked gives *a short proof*, which doesn’t seem to use the heavy machinery you mentioned. So it seems as if @Chrystomath‘s comment answers your question.